# How can I disable public access to the embed code of a map from Google My Maps?

Tags: maps, embed, mymaps

I am in the process of creating and publishing a map in Google My Maps, to show locations of various groups of businesses. The published map includes an option under the Share link to grab the embed code so as to publish the map elsewhere. I view the content of my map as having a value, and don't want others to be able to publish it. Can I disable the Embed option in the Share menu? Searching Google help has not helped.

Answer (score 0):

I dont believe you can prevent users from downloading or sharing your google my maps. If you need to embed it, you will need to share it first. Once you share it, its accessible by anyone. Once its accessible, there is no way to prevent people from downloading, embedding or further sharing your data.

You can restrict whom you share it with but i guess you already know that and it is not what you want.

I am myself extremely interested in knowing if there is a solution/workaround to this

Answer (score 0):

You can't disable it in google my maps so you have to use another mapping platform. The best solution i found was [MapHub](https://maphub.net/) the only one with similar quality. But the feature to disable download and control shearing is not free unfortunately.